# Expression tree modification

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have this

```
expression = expression.And(c => (c.Parameter.ValueType != Domain.Entities.ValueType.Selection 
                                   && SqlFunctions.PatIndex(value, c.Value) > 0
                                  )
                                  ||
                                  (c.Parameter.ValueType == Domain.Entities.ValueType.Selection 
                                   && value == c.LookupValue.Code
                                  )
                            );
```

I need to modify it so that there can be more than one values (user can select multiple choices now from a drop down list). Any ideas?

Comment: So `Domain.Entities.ValueType.Selection` is now a `List<>` rather than a single value?

Comment: No "value" now is not a single one. So I have a list of values and by iterating it i need to rebuild this expression. The values need to be combined with OR. e.g. (c.Parameter.ValueType == Domain.Entities.ValueType.Selection && (value1 == c.LookupValue.Code) || (value2 == c.LookupValue.Code));

Comment: I think I'm pretty close to understanding this, but it seems like it needs a bit more to really fill it out and be a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - can you add more information about what you're passing in and what you expect to get out?

Comment: Just imagine a search form with many filters. When the filter was a single selection one the expression was build like mentioned above and then you have sth like results=context.any(expression). Now this expression needs to take into account more than one selected values.